# Como integrar SearchView en FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, searchview

Estoy tratando de integrar un SearchView para una lista creada con FirebaseRecyclerViewApdater pero hasta ahora no he encontrado ninguna forma de hacerlo, estaria muy agradecido con quien me ayude, gracias comunidad StackOverFlow.

```
private void fetch() {


    search_edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pulsator.start();


    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Notas");



    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Upload> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Upload>()
                    .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Upload>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Upload parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new Upload(snapshot.child("titulo").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("texto").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

      adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Upload, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.cuadros_de_textos, parent, false);





            return new ViewHolder(view);


        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position, Upload upload) {


            //Seteo el titulo y el texto al cuadro de texto
            holder.setTxtTitle(upload.getTitulo());
            holder.setTxtText(upload.getTexto());


        }

    };

      //Seteo el Adapter
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    adapter.stopListening();

     }


 }
```

Comment: Solo una duda técnica. ¿Por qué no ocupar un RecyclerView ordinario con los datos recuperados de firebase en una lista de Java?

Comment: Porque con un Adaptador normal no puedo pasar el key del item seleccionado a otra actividad, con FirebaseRecyclerViewApdapter es super fácil hacerlo.

Comment: Temía una respuesta como esa. ¿Cómo es eso que no puedes pasar el key del item a otra actividad? Lo puedes hacer fácilmente en el método onBindViewHolder y desde ahí iniciar una nueva actividad con el contexto principal.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo?, Porque si funciona como dices cambio el Adaptador por uno normal.

Comment: Sí, claro, esta pregunta también se hizo en la comunidad en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819687/6119009

Comment: También te recomiendo que veas este ejemplo https://kodlogs.com/42488/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick

Comment: Lo voy a ver y te cuento.

Comment: Realmente crees que funciona?, Antes usaba un Adaptador normal y no me funciona, ponía el valor de la position pero ese valor no era el valor del child, así que por eso también me cambié a FirebaseRecyclerViewApdapter